# How to use grid with bootstrap for form (v3)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting with the grids used in Bootstrap and I would like my form to look like this using grid, this for my mobile version.

[image]

Currently my desktop version is looking like this:

[image]

The following is my HTML code with which I build my form, it is made with the help of PHP in a function:

```
public function userDate(){
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<table class="table">';
        echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>                 
            <td class="columna-titulo">Employee</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Name</td><td class="columna-valor" colspan="2">''</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>';
        echo '<tr>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Date</td><td class="columna-valor" id="TdFechaIngreso">''</td>
            <td class="columna-tituloYears Old</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo"Department</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            </tr>';                                        
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';        
    }
```

I am supporting myself with the following documentation but I find a solution [Documentation Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid)

**UPDATE:**

Performing the first answer, adding `.col-sm-12` still no change is reflected in my form

```
public function userDate(){
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<table class="table">';
        echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>                  
            <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Employee</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Name</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12" colspan="2">''</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>';
        echo '<tr>
            <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Date</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12" id="TdFechaIngreso">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Years Old</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Department</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
            </tr>';                                        
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
        
    }
```

You know that I have wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just add .col-sm-12 to every td you have. for example

```
<td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">
```

Above is for small devices. For medium devices use .col-md-12 and for large .col-lg-12

Comment: I tried but no change was applied to the form, check my last update do what you told me

Comment: Have you imported boostrap file in your html?

Comment: I have it imported into a javascript file like this `<script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5HELqxss1ypVR3j5ELq9tnep1 anonymous "> </script>`

Comment: You need to import css file as well.

Comment: I am using bootstrap css file as I use it to handle other grids